# Member's books in possession in Library System

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Hello I am currently working into a library system and I do want to view how many books are in possession of a specific member.

I want to add a copies to student whenever I issue a book to them.

I have tried:

```
public void StudentPossession()
    {
        cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblStudent(stCopies) VALUES (@stCopies)", cn);
        cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stCopies", txtCopies.Text);
        cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
```

but it doesn't insert into members row, instead it shows

```
|-------------|---------------|------------|
|   ID        |  studNumber   |  Copies    |
|-------------|---------------|------------|
|   1         |  34543534     |    NULL    |
|-------------|---------------|------------|
|   2         |  NULL         |    1       |
|-------------|---------------|------------|
```

I have also tried:

```
cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblStudent(stCopies) VALUES (@stCopies) WHERE studNumber ='" + txtStudNumber.Text + "'", cn);
```

But doesn't work either.

I don't know how to fix this so any help would be appreciated. Or is there anyway how to achieve this?

Comment: Why do you expect `studNumber` to be filled if you only pass a value for `stCopies`? Where do you expect `studNumber` to come from?

Comment: @John how can I also pass a value to my studNumber or a condition so it will be inserted to the rows of a student?

Comment: Do you want to insert new rows or update existing rows?

Comment: @John i do want to insert new records to stCopies since there is no existing records yet

Comment: `(studNumber, stCopies) VALUES (@studNumber, @stCopies)`?

Comment: @John I forgot to mention that I already have values to the student rows except for the StCopies, and I want to insert a value to the StCopies whenever I issue a book so I can see how many books are in student's possession

Comment: _"I forgot to mention that I already have values to the student rows"_ - I'm not following? You said you're inserting new records, so you don't have a student row for the current studNumber, right? In case there's a problem with terminology: a single row in the database table is a record.

Comment: @John I sck at explaining but students rows already have studNumber, stLname, etc, and the only NULL values is the stCopies. I do want to insert a 1 value to stCopies whenever I issue a book

Comment: INSERT is used to insert a record into the database. A single row is a record. UPDATE is used to update a record. It seems very much like you want UPDATE because you already have the student records and want to update a single field within the record.

Comment: `I [suck] at explaining` well, the good news is that computers are notably even-tempered.

Comment: @greybeard And despite being able to perform many calculations per second, they are quite patient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to insert a new record:

```
cm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblStudent (studNumber, stCopies) VALUES (@studNumber, @stCopies)", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stCopies", txtCopies.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studNumber", txtStudNumber.Text);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

If you want to update an existing record, as opposed to inserting a new one, use this code:

```
cm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblStudent SET stCopies = @stCopies WHERE studNumber = @studNumber", cn);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@stCopies", txtCopies.Text);
cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studNumber", txtStudNumber.Text);
cm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Also, it's [not recommended](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) to use `AddWithValue` for strings. Instead you should prepare values like so:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@studNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value= txtStudNumber.Text;
```

Where `VarChar` is the type of the field in the database, and `30` is the maximum length of the field in the database. From this code I would expect to see `VARCHAR(30)`.